# Numbers Won't Increment

Tags: java

First my call back to increment I know is not correct.  I am not sure what to do.  I need increment to use temp when it hits that case that requires that call back.  I can't change increment to pass a parameter into it because the graders test script wont allow for it.  The second problem is that it wont increment any input.  For instance if you just call increment on the number 23 it just returns 23.  The test script for the grader looks something like this:

```
public class TestBigNaturalSimple {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigNatural b1 = new BigNatural(); // default constructor
    BigNatural b2 = new BigNatural(23); // one-argument int constructor
    BigNatural b3 = new BigNatural("346"); // one-argument String constructor
    BigNatural b4 = new BigNatural(b2); // one-argument BigNatural
                                        // constructor

    b1.increment();
    b3.decrement();

    System.out.println(b1.toString()); // should print out 1
    System.out.println(b4.toString()); // should print out 23
}
}
```

My code is:

```
public class BigNatural {

private String num; 

public BigNatural(String input) {
    num = input;
}


public BigNatural(BigNatural input) {
    num = input.toString();
}

public BigNatural(Integer input) {
    num = input.toString();
}

public BigNatural() {
    Integer i = 0;
    num = i.toString();
}

public void increment() {
    Integer first = 0;
    Character ch = num.charAt(num.length()-1);
    Integer last = Character.digit(ch, 10);

    if (num.length() > 1)
    {
        if (last < 9) {
            last++;
        }
        else
            {
            if (num.length() >= 2)
            {
                last = 0;
                String temp = new String(num.substring(0, num.length()-2));
                increment();
            }
            else
            {
                last++;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (last < 9)
        {
            last++;
        }
        else
        {
            last = 0;
            first = 1;
        }
    }

    String t = last.toString();


    if (first > 0)
    {
    String x = first.toString();
    num.concat(x);
    }

    num.concat(t);
}

public void decrement() {
    Character ch = num.charAt(num.length()-1);
    Integer last = Character.digit(ch, 10);

    if(num.length() > 1)
    {
        if(last == 0)
        {
            String temp = new String(num.substring(0, num.length()-2));
            decrement();
        }
        else
        {
        last--;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(last > 0)
        {
            last--;
        }
        else
        {
            last = 0;
        }
    }

    String t = last.toString();
    num.concat(t);
}


public String toString() {
    return num;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That has to be the most complicated way to increment a number I have ever seen. ;) I assume you have to do it that way.

From what I can see you don't change `num` anywhere.  I would expect this to be obvious if you used a debugger. ;)

Try using `num = num.concat(t)` if you expect num to change.

Note: String is immutable so you cannot change it, you can only replace it.

EDIT: Here is a version provided for your own interest.  Your professor will know you didn't write this, so don't copy it. ;)

```
public void increment() {
    num = increment(num);
}
private static String increment(String s) {
    if (s.length() <= 0) return "1";
    char ch = s.charAt(s.length() - 1);
    String top = s.substring(0, s.length() - 1);
    return ch < '9' ? top + ++ch : increment(top) + '0';
}
```

Comment: you know it has been a long night when you miss that.  well we are getting somewhere now.  the only other big problem i am having is how to call increment on temp for when the base case is > 9

Comment: It appears you are trying to use recusrion. To do that you need to pass all your arguments as parameters and return a result. Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: yeah, originally i had temp.increment() so that it will call increment on temp, but i soon found out that would not work.

Comment: Can you try what I suggested? One `public void increment()` and another `private String increment(String)` method?

Comment: yeah, just give me a minute, i realized that when it was concatenating it was adding extra numbers on, fixed that and ill change it so it passes a parameter.

Comment: i think i got it on my own.  I just changed the whole String temp line to num = num.substring(0, num.substing(0, num.length() -2) that way when it calls back to increment num has been changed.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable in Java. Hence, the code

```
num.concat(t);
```

in your increment method will not do what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

First, apply the rule *don't repeat yourself*:

- to increment is to add 1
- to decrement is to add -1

Thus you simply need to write on function that takes a number as input and add it to your BigNatural:

```
public void increment() {
  add(1);
}

public void decrement() {
  add(-1);
}

private void add(int i) {
  // Your homework here ...
  // You will have only one function to debug and correct, not 2
}
```

Second: as pointed in other answers, `num.concat(t);` does not do what you expect, you'll need `num = num.concat(t);`. Always refer to the Java documentation when you use a function you don't know. If you don't have an editor that allows you to debug your programs, I strongly suggest you get one: Eclipse for instance but other editors might be better as learning tool. The added benefit is that the tools will format the code for you, warn you about lots of mistakes, ...

Comment: +0: Given the complex way the increment is perform, I don't think this is the issue, not do I think implementing add will help. ;)